# Get latest Solana token transfers

Tags: web3.js, jsonrpc-api, mainnet

I need to get the latest transactions that have Solana token transfers. For this I tried out the `blockSubscribe` WSS method but it seems to be throwing errors. I am using Alchemy WSS on the mainnet for my purpose.

```
[Symbol(kType)]: 'message',
[Symbol(kData)]: '{"id":"1","jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid/Unspported params for blockSubscribe."}}'
```

I am not sure what am doing wrong here as I am just following what the docs said [here](https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/blocksubscribe).

Below is my code -

```
const socket = new WebSocket(WSS_ENDPOINT);

socket.addEventListener("open", () => {
  const subscribeMessage = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: "1",
    method: "blockSubscribe",
    params: [{ filter: "all" }],
  };

  console.log("WSS stream started");
  const messageString = JSON.stringify(subscribeMessage);
  socket.send(messageString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The params are a little off, so you should be able to just pass the string "all" instead of an object with the "filter" key. Try this:

```
const subscribeMessage = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: "1",
    method: "blockSubscribe",
    params: ["all"],
};
```

Comment: I have tried both "all" and the one I have in my question as params, neither of them work

Comment: The RPC server that you're using might not have this endpoint enabled, since it's very expensive and disabled by default.